# how to iterate over an array of objects in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

I have an array of objects that i have received from my web API, and i am using handlebars to create a template and iterate over these objects. However i am unsure on how i iterate over my array of objects.

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/api/CaseStudies/top", function (data) {

        var caseStudies = [];
        for (var i = 0, caseStudie; (caseStudie = data[i]); ++i) {
            caseStudies.push(caseStudie);
        }
        //console.log(caseStudies);

        renderTemplate(caseStudies);  
    });

    function renderTemplate(caseStudies) {
        var template = $('#test').html();
        var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
        var html = templateScript(caseStudies);
        $("#output").append(html);
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
 <script id="test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <div>

       {{#each caseStudies}}
          The title is {{Title}}And my name is{{Name}}<br />
       {{/each}}
     </div>
   </script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

The array of objects i receive from my api looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of your for loop is.  It looks like it is making an exact copy of the data array into another array

Comment: Other than that, it's been a while since I did handlebars, but your usage of `{{#each caseStudies}}` to me suggests that the data given to the `compile()` should be in the form of `{ caseStudies: [...] }`, not just a pure array.  It is expecting to find that property on the data you give to the compile.

Comment: Yes i gathered that was what it was trying to look for but how do i achieve that result with what i have. Thanks

Comment: Just construct an object with a key of `caseStudies` and assign your array to it.  And give that object to the compile method

Comment: `templateScript({ caseStudies: caseStudies });`

Comment: That wont work though as you can only pass strings to the compile method,

Comment: I was mistakenly saying to do that change to the compile method.  That should be done to your `templateScript` variable

Comment: ye that works, thanks bro